# Display EmbedLink player with access token

Tags: video-streaming, google-drive-api, google-oauth

In my Java web application I need to show videos stored in a Google Drive account to unauthenticated users.

I managed to solve this using OAuth2 from Google API in server application to retrieve an access token and the DownloadUrl attribute of the video file. Then adding the access token to the URL this way:

```
https://doc-10-8g-docs.googleusercontent.com/...&access_token=XXXXXXXX
```

I pass this URL to the front-end application, either a HTML5 video player or Flash video player, and it works.

But I'd like to know if it's possible to use Google Drive video player in a similar way, for few reasons:

- It's live streaming. You don't need to wait for buffering to fetch any part of the video
- Support for more video formats (MKV, divx, etc.)
- Video Quality selector

I tried to use EmbedLink from Drive API with access_token parameter in a similar way but it doesn't work.

Alternative solution could be to play real streaming in the Flash/HTML5 player. That should be enough for mi purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution myself, by looking the requests Google Drive embed player does.

Basically you make a request for this address:

```
https://docs.google.com/get_video_info?authuser=&docid=<YOUR_VIDEO_ID>
```

You can do it using Drive client after OAuth authentication or attach `&access_token=YOUR_TOKEN` at the end of the URL. Both options work.

The response consists in URL Encoded pairs of field and value, with info about the video. The interesting field for our porpuse is `fmt_stream_map`, which contains a list of available streams in various formats and codecs. These URL can be send to a Flash or HTML5 Player, which will reproduce it without authentication needed.

If you want to start the video in any specific moment, just add `&begin=MILLISECONDS` at the end of the stream URL.

NOTE: You can get the URL list from the field `url_encoded_fmt_stream_map`. It's a little more difficult to parse, but contains other useful information like video mime type and codecs.

An example code:

```java
Credential credential = getOAuth2Credential(); //Your authentication stuff

//Create a new authorized API client
Drive service = new Drive.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), credential).build();

String fileId = "XXXXXXXXXXX"; //Your video docid in Google Drive

HttpResponse resp = service.getRequestFactory()
        .buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl("https://docs.google.com/get_video_info?authuser=&docid=" + fileId)).execute();

//Convert response InputStream to String
String content = "";
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(resp.getContent());
int ch = 0;
while (ch != -1) {
    ch = isr.read();
    if (ch != -1) content += (char)ch;  
}

//Split response in pairs field / value
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(content, "&");

while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
    String token = st.nextToken();
    if (token.split("=").length == 2) {
        String field = token.split("=")[0];
        String value = URLDecoder.decode(token.split("=")[1], "UTF-8");
        if ("url_encoded_fmt_stream_map".equals(field)) {
            //Prints info of each available video Stream
            String[] urlList = value.split(",");
            for (int i=0; i < urlList.length; i++) {
                System.out.println("Stream #" + i + ":");
                System.out.println("URL: " + URLDecoder.decode(urlList[i].split("&")[1].split("=")[1], "UTF-8"));
                System.out.println("Quality: " + URLDecoder.decode(urlList[i].split("&")[3].split("=")[1], "UTF-8"));
                String type = URLDecoder.decode(urlList[i].split("&")[2], "UTF-8");
                if (type.indexOf(';') > 0) {
                    System.out.println("Mime type: " + type.substring(5, type.indexOf(';')));
                    System.out.println("Codecs: " + type.substring(type.indexOf("codecs=\"") + 8, type.lastIndexOf('"')));
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("Mime type: " + type.substring(5));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I know that Google's `File` class has a method getEmbedLink -- couldn't this be what you are looking for? I don't fully understand it though -- sometime getEmbedLink is null, sometimes it gives me a link directly to the file, like a preview

Comment: The problem with embedlink is that it checks for an authenticated user in the browser, which doesn't work for me.

Comment: That also would not work for me. What link should be used if we want something like a "preview" of the doc, that does not require authentication?